# Is there a correct way to use a JavaScript module in a TypeScript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I really hope this isn't an opinion question, and I don't think it is...

Is there a correct way to include a JS module in a TS project? If I don't do one of the 2 steps below, my IDE (linter, wahtever) gives me `TS2307: Cannot find module` when I use the line `import * as myPackage from 'myPackage'`.

The steps I use are

```
npm i thePackage --save
typings i -g thePackage --save // assuming it has a typings
```

If the module doesn't have a typings, all you do is

```
declare let myPackage:any
```

Is that all you have to do in order to use an external package in a TS project? Or am I missing a vital step?

I know I could create a .d.ts file, but for now, I'd like to get the hang of TS without spending all my time writing those files.

I've also been reading about `DefinitelyTyped` and `@types/myPackage`, but I don't know much about it...

Comment: You can read more about @types here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If the package has declaration files

In TypeScript 2.0+, for a package `the-package`

```
npm install --save @types/the-package
```

---

### If the package doesn't have declaration files

If the package doesn't have declaration files for it, create a file named `externals.d.ts` with the following:

```
// This file should contain no top-level imports or exports.
declare module "the-package";
```

> Note: If there's more than one thing you can import from `the-package`, you can use a wildcard as well:
>
> ```
> declare module "the-package/*";
> ```

At this point, you can do basically whatever you want with the package when you import it - it comes in as `any`.

---

### Strongly typing the package

If you want to add some type safety, we'll start defining the module in its own file in a folder called `externals`.

So we'll write out `./externals/the-package/index.d.ts`.

```
export function foo(): void;
export function bar(x: string): number;
```

And now add the following to your `tsconfig.json`'s compiler options.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["externals/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

Now any modules should be looked up in `externals` first before being looked up in `@types` & `node_modules`.

> Note: This assumes `externals` is in the same directory as `tsconfig.json`. Adjust appropriately.

Once your module is fully written out, you can send a PR for this package to DefinitelyTyped if you'd like to help others out.

Comment: Is `externals.d.ts` supposed to go in a certain directory, or is it top level? 
Also, `typings` uses a more up to date package than `@types`. For example, `typings i -S bluebird` installs version `3.4.1` whereas `npm i -S @types/bluebird` installs version `3.0.35`.

Comment: `externals.d.ts` could go anywhere you want. I'd just put it in the top level of my `src` folder. I'm not sure why the `@types` version is older, but I'll check into it.